# Stata graph and yline

Tags: graph, stata

I have the following `twoway scatter` and I am looking to plot two `ylines` and have them start and stop at set x-values.

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

twoway scatter  mpg weight, /// 
    connect(l) sort ///
    xline(2500) ///
    yline(25)
```

I want an `xline` at 2500 and two `yline` one from 1500 to 2800 and the other `xline` from 2900 to 4100. I also want the data points to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hack would be to use auxiliary variables:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

*----- first yline -----

gen xli = .
replace xli = 1500 in 1
replace xli = 2800 in l

gen yli = 25

*----- second yline -----

gen xxli = .
replace xxli = 2900 in 1
replace xxli = 4100 in l

gen yyli = 20

*----- first xline -----

gen yyyli = .
replace yyyli = 15 in 1
replace yyyli = 40 in l

gen xxxli = 2500

*----- graph -----

twoway scatter  mpg weight, connect(l) sort || ///
    line yli xli || line yyli xxli /// ylines
        || line yyyli xxxli // xline
```

I doubt it's the best technique, but it seems to work. You would need to work at least on the legend and line colors. `help <command>` and the Stata manuals have a lot on that (and much more).

Comment: Well I hope for Stata's sake there is an easier way to do this. Your hack works, but when I try to connect the lines and sort in my graph, the line no longer shows. Any ideas? I should have included this in the question, but figured that the options would not be affected

Comment: Please show us some code reproducing the problem. My guess is, well  you've said it,  the `sort`, but I can't be sure. The strategy is not that bad.  Just create the data needed to draw the lines. That's first principles.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this:

```
sysuse auto 
scatter mpg weight, connect(l) sort || scatteri 25 1500 25 2800, recast(line)
```

`scatteri` by default just adds points at the coordinates mentioned, i.e. 25 1500 and 25 2800 which are (y, x) pairs following `scatter` and `twoway` convention that the y variable is named first.

The `recast()` option recasts the `scatter` as a `line` graph. To get separate line segments, add separate `scatteri` calls.

Comment: A much better solution.